# d3 animated Treemap CSV - NOT zoomable

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to create an animated d3 Treemap, like in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/Rnhatch/1820583

The Problem is, that this code uses a JSON file but I will have a CSV file.

The main idea is to change/ animate the Treemap with some filters (for example age filter)

Do you know some example code, where they also animate the content of the Treemap with buttons and use a CSV file?

Here is another example: (but it is not working) http://bl.ocks.org/jarobertson/1446865

I looked for hours but I coundnt find something.

My coding skills are to bad to change such a code. I hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to adjust the data access component to use D3's csv parser.  (Line 71 of the Gist).  Here are the docs for that:  https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/v1.1.1/README.md#dsv_parse

This Gist is really old and I'm sure Mike Bostok has provided much better ways of getting your requirements achieved in the 8 years since I created it.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob! Thanks for creating an account for my question!